# Has Booking.com blocked sending files in conversations?

Tags: booking.com

This May I was able to send a picture of my ID to a hotel via booking.com's message tool. I don't remember exactly how I did it, but most likely I just drag-and-dropped the file into the message area, and it got sent. Today I haven't been able to do the same thing.

Are guests still able to send files to their hosts in booking.com? If so, how do we do it?

Comment: Obligatory scam warning, Booking.com hotel accounts get hijacked a lot and I would not trust sending my ID through the chat

Comment: Is it possible you tried an image file (JPEG or PNG) and are now trying a PDF? Not sure about any rule change or any restrictions for guests but I saw a lot of discussions / questions from “partners” about the fact that sharing a PDF is not possible.